# How many pages in a multi-page TIFF?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

In python, how does one count the number of pages/frames in a multi-page TIFF?

Comment: why would you count them? why not read it from the file header?

Comment: Erm, I never mentioned PIL. And "very well" is quite fuzzy terminology. Give an answer (is that not the purpose of stackoverflow?)!

Comment: you tagged your question with python-imaging-library, so how did you "never mention PIL"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pillow, the fork of PIL, is supposed to work well for TIFFs (http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#tiff)

A way to achieve what you want is to print the specific variables `n_frames` :

```
from PIL import Image

try:
    img = Image.open('multipage_tiff_example.tif')
    img.load()
    print(img.n_frames)
except:
    print("Unable to load image")
```